# Google Analytics data Missing for 4 days

Tags: php, google-analytics

I used wrong tracking id in my E-commerce tracking code for Google analytics and missed the data for few days.

To add that missing data in my account I have written a short script which manually send all orders data for four days to GA account but what my concern is date : Those orders which already placed on different dates and , when if I run my script and so it will send my missing data with current date , which I do not want. ( I want to send date when that order is actually placed)

do anyone help me with this ?

I am really much stuck with my work here.

Answer (score 2):

might not be your fault, our GA accounts are now missing 4 days data across the board

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/-gqkeG8ru-c

Comment: That thread contains a link to Google's issue dashboard about it: http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&ts=1383116399000&sid=18&iid=09b481d25b7ac7fdf174e93a0ea0b4cf